# 'str' object is not callable, but I'm not using "str" at all

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm using [Google Colab](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/) for development. My script only has one line of code where I'm supposed to read input from the console:

```
question = input("Hello")
```

But it is throwing this error: `'str' object is not callable`

I search for similar problems and all of them where related to code using "str" as a variable or function name so it needed to be renamed, but in my case it is literally one line of code and I'm not using "str" at all.

Here is a screenshot of Google Colab:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I tried this in a brand new notebook and it worked. In your notebook it appears that `input` is not the built-in function to read user input but is actually a string of some sort.

To debug this further, try changing the code to just say `input`. Then it will print what the `input` identifier is bound to. You ought to see something like `<bound method Kernel.raw_input of <google.colab._kernel.Kernel object at 0x7f9fb5f40210>>`...

[image: screenshot of new notebook]

...but I suspect you'll see something else.

Answer (score 3):

somewhere above you have

`input = something_that_is_a_string`

and that is shadowing the builtin input

dont name your variables input

Comment: But there is nothing avobe, I only have one script with one line of code, I'm not using input as a variable name

Answer (score 2):

You have a string variable named `input` previously in your code. Or perhaps you previously had such a variable and deleted the code, but the variable is still in the namespace. Just restart your Google Colab environment from the top menu: `Runtime --> Restart Runtime`. That will clear out all variables from memory and let you start over.

Answer (score 0):

try this before your code.

```
del(input)
```